# Two year spot rate meaning

Tags: fixed-income

I am trying to understand the concept of spot rates better.

Does a 2-year spot rate indicate the rate you get for a two year bond or the rate you should discount the second year cash flow for an annual coupon bond?
Same for a 3-year spot rate.

Answer (score 4):

The 2-year spot rate is the rate at which you discount the year 2 cashflows.
If the bond has no coupon, has a two year maturity, and is fairly priced then the 2-year spot rate is the yield to maturity of the bond (or as you say 'the rate you get').